# When listbox item is selected display related data in another listbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, windows, listboxitem

I am building an app with WPF C# and trying to display values in a list box which shows when an item from another list box is selected. Both list boxes need to get data from my SQL database.

listboxes when nothing is selected:

[image: How listboxes should look when nothing is selected]

kistboxes when an item is selected:

[image: How listboxes should look when an item is selected]

This is how I display the values in the first list box (before anyone says it, I know it is vulnerable to SQL injection).

C#:

```cs
public void TradeList() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Trade from tblTrades", sqlConTwo);
    adpt.Fill(dt);

    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
        Area.Items.Add(dr["Trade"].ToString());
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="TradesSelected" Width="665" BorderBrush="#FF939393" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
  <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="Trade" Width="665" Height="100" BorderBrush="#FF939393" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1 0 1 1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Trade}" SelectionChanged="Trade_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Margin="10 0 0 0">
  <TextBox x:Name="SkillSelected" Width="665" BorderBrush="#FF939393" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
  <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="Skills" Width="665" Height="100" BorderBrush="#FF939393" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1 0 1 1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Skills}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

In my table, the column with the skills in it is called Skills. I have found a way to do it by hard-coding all the trades and skills in, but this is not ideal as there are a lot of rows in my table, and this would be very time-consuming.

Comment: the observable collection `Trade` should contain all the sub elements! These should not be an seperate observable collection.
then your secund Listbox should be bount to the first Listbox.selectedItem and display the subitems....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you have 2 `ObservableCollection` `Skills` and `Trade` in `ListBoxs` `SelectedItem` will get the select item of the list box so when `Trade_SelectionChanged` occurred u can get the selected skill and fill `Trade`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed issue with Trade_SelectionChanged the fix was right in front of my eyes all along..